# kendo if else when null

Tags: templates, if-statement, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to have a template that always shows what is in odata table except null values, for example, in this example, I tried to make a condition which will check if UnitOfMeasure is null, if it is, it should display only Quantity value, if it is not, Quantity+UnitOfMeasure. Here is what I tried. Thanks

```
template: "#if(UnitOfMeasure == null) {#= kendo.toString(Quantity, "n2")#} else{#= kendo.toString(Quantity, "n2")#  #=UnitOfMeasure#}#"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template: "#=kendo.toString(Quantity, 'n2')##=UnitOfMeasure == null ? '' : UnitOfMeasure#"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, have you missed something?

Comment: when I don't use your code, my site works, everything except this thing, when I put your code I got just comment field and title of the page, I tried once again

Comment: I just changed some double quotes to single quotes. Try it now. However, keep in mind that I'm handing you a string of letters and symbols with the hope that you will read it to understand it. I'm under the impression that you simply copy pasted my code instead of reading it and implementing it, which is a very bad thing. If you did try to understand it, you would have noticed I nested the quotes by mistake (and lack of syntax coloring).

Comment: thank you, it works now, I am new in Kendo and I am not quite familiar with syntax, sorry

Comment: You are welcome! And please do not forget to mark the correct answer.